# About the force on a rotating wing seed

Tags: forces, rotation, turbulence

Every matured (ready to fall), wing seed ends up in a rotating motion, no matter what it's initial position is (the seed follows the path of least action or in more colloquial language, the path of least resistance). How this comes about is for my question of no relevance,  but for those interested in how the rotation starts, see [here](http://dragonfly.tam.cornell.edu/publications/2012_nonlinearity_kapil.pdf)).

[image]

What interests me is the state in which the seed is rotating and descending. Let's assume there is no wind. The wind is, in fact, of most importance for the seeds to travel as far as possible, but just leave the wind out right now.
The study of the rotating seeds without wind we can perform the best in the lab conditions. Which some people, which can be read in [this](http://www.caltech.edu/news/maple-seeds-and-animals-exploit-same-trick-fly-1540) article.

They found that the upwards directed aerodynamic force was created by little vertices ("tornadoes") appearing on the upper side of the seed's wing. They suck air away from the upper side of the wing thereby creating a pressure difference pointing upwards, so the force associated with this pressure difference is pointing upwards. This force is exactly the same in magnitude, but opposite in direction to the gravitational force acting on the seed (the descending seed has a constant velocity). The falling seed diminished its potential energy thereby constantly supplying energy to maintain the rotation.

Now if we let the wing seed "experience" a vertical and constant wind so that the seed stands still in the air, it is essentially the same situation as the seed descending in the air without wind. Of course, the upward wind has to be carefully adjusted to have the same velocity as the same descending seed without wind.

My question is: doesn't the last example (the seed being stationary) show that the force responsible for the upward force, while the seed is descending, is the change of direction in the momentum of the air when hitting the lower side of the seed (contrary to the "vortices" explanation)?

Comment: My sincere apologies, I wrote 2  comments earlier regarding bird flight which I now realise were of no real relevance to your interesting question. I deleted them and upvoted. The best of luck with your question, (which, imo,   might be helped by an image of a magnified seed airfoil.)

Comment: -1. Unclear. You appear to be asking "Do Maple Seeds and Animals Exploit the Same Trick to Fly?" which is answered by the linked Caltech article.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Maybe I **appear** to be asking that, but in fact, I'm not.